# Display embedded PDF in Vaadin Subwindow in Chrome

Tags: java, pdf, google-chrome, vaadin

I have a Vaadin application and I am trying to display a PDF which I am reading from locally as a PDF stored on my web server.

```
        setCaption(mainApp.getMsg("app.subwindow.help.title"));
    setHeight("750px");
    setWidth("1000px");
    setModal(true);
    setDraggable(false);
    setResizable(false);
    setBorder(Window.BORDER_MINIMAL);
    setScrollable(true);

    VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();
    vl.setSpacing(true);    
    vl.setSizeFull();

    Embedded pdf = new Embedded("test", new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {     
            public InputStream getStream() {
                InputStream is = PdfWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Lifestyle-Tracker-Promo.pdf");
                return is;
            }
        }, "file.pdf", mainApp));       

    pdf.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
    pdf.setMimeType("application/pdf"); 

    pdf.setSizeFull(); 
    vl.addComponent(pdf);   

    addComponent(vl);
```

I am trying to display the PDF in a embedded PDF reader on the page.  The code works fine with IE8 and Firefox but it refuses to play nice with Chrome's embedded PDF reader.  Has anyone else encountered this issue and has any suggestions?

Comment: Go to `chrome://plugins` and make sure the integrated pdf viewing plugin is enabled (Chrome PDF Viewer).

Comment: Chrome PDF Viewer is enabled.

Comment: @anataliocs : did you check your log file/console if there is an exception?

Comment: No exceptions.  I think its purely a browser related issue.

Comment: Started bug ticket: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/8387

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the content to full, did you try setting your vertical layout as the window's content?

```
Window window = new Window();
        ((VerticalLayout) window.getContent()).setSizeFull();

Embedded pdf = new Embedded("test", new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {     
            public InputStream getStream() {
                InputStream is = PdfWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Lifestyle-Tracker-Promo.pdf");
                return is;
            }
        }, "file.pdf", mainApp));   

pdf.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
pdf.setMimeType("application/pdf"); 
pdf.setSizeFull();

window.addComponent(pdf);
getMainWindow().addWindow(window);
```

Comment: Under further testing, ((VerticalLayout) window.getContent()).setSizeFull(); caused a display error in Safari.  I had to set the Height and Width manually and that did the trick.  Otherwise great solution.

Comment: i meant window.setContent(vl) where vl is you vl in your code example. i have not tested that. but thanks for the hint with safari, never testet my application in safari... :)

Comment: Also in IE8, if your vertical layout height is bigger then the subwindow, and the subwindow has a scroll it can mess up other plug-ins or items you have set not visible in your main window.  Can't explain it.  #AnotherReasonToHateIE ;)